# Which sources allow fixing link-only answers easily by copy-pasting?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I've noticed a lot of link-only answers that I could theoretically fix by simply sticking in an appropriate quote from the link, but I just *don't have the patience* to trawl through gazillions of pages of dense legalese to see if maybe this site would allow copy-pasting certain parts, hmm, maybe if I apply this part of the fair use doctrine, but what about…. And since I edit several hundred posts a month across the network, I think it's fair to assume a lot of editors would have similar feelings, if not more so.

(In some of these cases, I might have the technical background to have a decent shot of summarizing the answer from the link given, but since I almost always run across these in review, I'm not eager to spend twenty minutes digging into *one* answer's background to try to reconstruct the author's frame of mind when I could be handling a *couple dozen* other posts instead. So that's out.)

However, if I knew that I didn't have to make a tricky determination of the legal situation every time, I think I could justify the minimal effort of finding a suitable-looking quote to pull rather more easily. And hopefully this would apply to others as well, especially if we publicized this a bit.

Therefore, is there a cheatsheet of relatively common websites that always/usually/seldom/never have CC-BY-SA-compatible content to directly haul into link-only answers?

Comment: would *fair use* cover your use of content for explaining a link?

Comment: @Dagon: I mentioned that briefly, but I am not particularly confident that fair use can unequivocally justify *all* possible future CC-BY-SA uses. I'm not even sure it necessarily works for the limited case of an ordinary answer, given the vagaries of different sites' terms of service and the quirks of something explicitly designed as a four-prong guide to judging the merits of cases *individually* (read: unpredictably to anyone but a lawyer at best). Never mind the fact that fair use is basically US-only, as such.

Comment: Realistically, there's no point in even worrying about copyright *because* of these sorts of fuzzy edges. And also because nearly any dispute will be handled via [the DMCA-mandated process](http://stackexchange.com/legal#15CopyrightPolicy) rather than ever seeing court. "Don't be a jerk to folks who are putting useful info on the 'Net" is both less fuzzy and probably more effective.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of the license, you'll want to make sure such quotations are [properly attributed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) - it's just good manners.

And if you're properly attributing the quote *and* ensuring that you're just quoting a key portion of the target rather than duplicating the entire article... Then there's a reasonable chance that the quotation falls under fair use. Crucially, you're *not* claiming ownership of the text you're quoting.

In short, I wouldn't worry too much about it unless you're grabbing entire pages or grabbing quotes from pages where the author makes it abundantly clear that any and all quotation is frowned on (in which case, just flag the answer - these tend to not be particularly stable sources). Give credit where credit is due and most folks are perfectly happy to be quoted.