# Rewrite link-only answer completely with extensive quote reformatting, or just write my own answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, link-only-answers, attribution

Every so often (say, about five times a day, and usually in a review queue) I come across a link-only answer that could probably be rewritten to include a direct quote of most or all of the original. Or, it could be deleted. Hitherto I have been picking between those, depending mostly on the amount of energy I can spare to the tedious and thankless task of fixing all the copy-paste formatting for a quote some lazy slob three years ago couldn't be bothered to add to their rep-hunting answer. All so *they* can avoid having *their poor answer* deleted, and perhaps even gain a bit of rep.

But perhaps there's a better way, one which, well, rewards those who actually do more work than find something to put in a throwaway comment. How appropriate is it to post my own answer with that same copy-paste job and a note that this was converted from a link-only answer by so-and-so?

Comment: At least it's not highly upvoted *plagiarized* answers we're talking about.

Comment: *Every so often (say, about five times a day)* +1!

Comment: "lazy slob" - now, now.

Comment: @Kev: Some of them seem awfully lazy! "Here, go read through six pages of miscellaneous documentation to see if you can spot the point I was getting at." But, y'know, little hyperbole too.

Comment: Be careful with copy-paste though, don't forget you must check the target's licensing before copying anything significant.

Comment: @spectras: Yes, e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308785/which-sources-allow-fixing-link-only-answers-easily-by-copy-pasting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I'm only talking about link-copied answers here. It looks obvious to me that if, in a similar situation, you already have an answer you think is better, then you shouldn't waste time writing a link-copied answer (just warn the author with a comment if you want), and you shouldn't hesitate to **post your own**. This is one of the main purposes of a Q&A site like Stack Overflow.

---

I think that adding a new answer copying from a link-only one is as much appropriated as much it will help the question (and relative correct answer) to be better understood by the users who'll read it <sup>(correct me if my english is wrong here)</sup>.

First of all, to be correct I would ask the poster of the link-only answer, with a comment, to better reason their answer. Chances are that the user will understand the lack of content of their post by their own, and edit it.

If this doesn't happen I would instead, before adding a new link-copied answer, see if it would actually makes sense asking myself some questions:

1. Did anyone already do something similar?
2. Is the thread recent and/or active enough for the new answer to be noticed?
3. Are there a reasonable amount of answers, so that the new one will actually be seen instead of falling down to the last page?
4. Additionally, is the effort spent to post the new answer worth it (for the sake of helping the community and not only for the hypothetical new reputation) or am I only going to waste an hour re-formatting text in Markdown?

If the answers for at least the first three points are {1: no, 2: yes, 3: yes}, then I think adding a new answer would be nice first of all to help the community, and maybe for reputational purposes too.

Comment: Good point on posting a comment first.

Comment: Agreed, best to let user a fair chance to improve his/her own answer before taking matters into your own hands with a "could have been better this way" comment. I learned a lot from those.

Comment: How long do you want to wait around for the OP to react? Five minutes? A day? A week? If it's a link-only answer, save the link in a comment or actual answer, if it's valuable, and then get it deleted. Should he bother to upgrade it to an answer later, he can undelete / ask for undeletion.

Comment: @Deduplicator the time you have to wait obviously **depends on the situation**. If you see a fast answer given to a question a few minutes ago then the user is probably still around it and will therefore read your notification in a few minutes, otherwise if the answer/question is old then I'd not expect a fast response (based on the recent activity of the user).

Comment: So, how long *would* you wait around, until you handle it? And are you sure you will actually follow up after that time is over, especially if it's longer?

Comment: @Deduplicator I, **personally**, would wait some hours if the post is very recent (0-60 minutes ago), one or two days if the post is recent enough (0-2 weeks ago), and around a week if the post is old (> 2 weeks ago).

Comment: @Deduplicator but again, if the post is old, I would first look at the recent activity of the user, and decide accordingly. Obviously I can't wait forever so going over one week is too much IMHO.

Answer (score 22):

Or, y'know, you could just write your own original 
answer and incorporate the link.

**Further Reading**
[Link-only Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link-only-answers)

Comment: B-B-B-But *originality*.

Answer (score 18):

I'm afraid that if we systematically edit lazily written link-only answers to become good answers, we're not going to do the site a favor in the long run. I think this because if the person who originally posted that poor answer now gets it upgraded “for free” and subsequently gains reputation for it, they will do it again.

Instead of doing work somebody else was too lazy to be bothered with so they can continue to gain reputation, if you think that you can do a better job and have the time, I think you should post your own answer. The offending answer should be left alone, down-voted and eventually be deleted. Whatever seems appropriate.

Answer (score 15):

Do what you do whenever you see that the existing answers on a question aren't good enough:

**Write your own!**

If this were not the normal order of things, every question would only have one answer.

Editing's great an' all, but there's still a reason each question may have multiple answers.