# Link Only Answer - Not An Answer Declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, accepted-answer, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591602/621316

I feel like this is a very straight-forward link only answer:

> See here: [Relationships, Navigation Properties, and Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

These kinds of answers stick out to me like a sore thumb because they tell me nothing whatsoever unless I leave the site. I personally don't see it having votes or being accepted as arguments for why it should be kept. Maybe it could be converted to a comment.

Comment: There are so many "why was my NAA declined" questions. There was a very popular request for updating the help text and I think someone should attend to it

Comment: Did you flag as VLQ or NAA?

Comment: @Tunaki not an answer

Comment: Google "entity framework create foreign key".  This Q+A is first, the MSDN page is second.   If we keep adding this kind of trivially googable q+a then that will surely reverse, problem solved.

Comment: reading about these, I do see that you are sometimes supposed to contact the author. in this case, I don't know if I feel that that would help, considering the answer contains nothing, and the external page does. blanket copying the source to the answer doesn't seem much better.

Comment: If you check your flag history, you'll find the moderator who declined the flag did try to explain why he did so. I've asked him to comment here. FWIW, there's some unusual context here: the asker followed that link to  a *different* article that solved his problem, added a link to that article as a comment on the answer and then *edited the question* to contain the answer; IOW, the trail of breadcrumbs was successfully documented but in a rather inappropriate fashion. I've tried to clean this up a bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posting another answer here, because I see a fair bit of confusion in the comments still. In particular, folks are getting sidetracked by the votes on the answer; the votes are a signal that there may be a good reason to preserve the answer, *but not themselves a reason to preserve the answer*.

In this case, the answer was at best the start of a trail of breadcrumbs that led to the answer. In fact, it *did* lead the asker to an answer, which he helpfully posted... As a screenshot... In the question. Along with further details in a link on the answer.

This creates a problem: the answer (as it originally was written) was not an answer; it should've been removed. However, doing so would've left the question unanswered save for a screenshot in the question *which would've been unreferenced without the answer!* As broken as the situation was, deleting that answer would've broken it further. **Moderators are not supposed to make problems worse.**

Anyone who flagged that answer could've fixed the larger problem, either by editing (as I did) or by posting their own answer. But no one did. I'm not even convinced that anyone took the time to evaluate the problem beyond "this answer is mostly a link".

Quite often, link-only answers are isolated issues; however, sometimes they represent the edge of a much larger problem with the question itself. A good signal for this scenario *is* the presence of a high score and/or acceptance - so if you see this, **take a step back and evaluate the situation** before flagging. The answer may not be a problem at all, or may indicate the presence of other work that needs to be done; in many cases, you'll be able to fix the issue without involving a moderator at all... And if you *can* do so, you *should* do so: Stack Overflow works only when we all pitch in to help.

Comment: Is the implication of "flagging" that "I think this should be deleted outright with no other thought applied" and not "There's definitely a problem here but I'm not qualified to fix it and need someone better than me to help"? There's a lot of judgement calls that you're making that I could not have made.

Comment: _"I'm not even convinced that anyone took the time to evaluate"_ -- well [I for one took the time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311753/link-only-answer-not-an-answer-declined#comment279822_311756). "checked if I can do it myself when it was brought to meta, and couldn't figure it"

Comment: The implication of flagging is that *you need a moderator's help*, @Sahuagin. You don't need a moderator's help to edit, or to answer, or to vote... And there's a good chance a random moderator isn't going to know any more about the topic than you do. 90% of the time, this doesn't matter: an obviously bad answer is bad. But that remaining 10%, there's something unusual going on - and that's when you need to stop and think (or ask on meta). Learning to recognize unusual situations is as important for flaggers as it is for moderators!

Comment: I don't think you flagged it, @gnat? You hadn't at the time I edited it at least.

Comment: if it wasn't at meta already, I would flag it (after trying to edit - score 20 and accept mark make solid signal that it may be worth a try)

Comment: "The implication of flagging is that you need a moderator's help" Not entirely, because VLQ and NAA go first to the review queue. That's often my intention when raising an NAA flag: I will downvote, delete vote, and then flag to get votes -- or disputation -- _from my fellow users_.

Comment: Not that different, @Josh; either way, you're soliciting assistance.

Answer (score 12):

I was the moderator who declined the not an answer flag you raised with the following custom decline message:

> This answer has been useful (check the score) -- please edit it so that it continues to be useful instead of flagging for deletion.

Given that this answer was an accepted answer with score 20, I think there's evidence that this answer has been helpful to a number of visitors through its 2+ years of existence. Given this, I don't think the best course of action is summarily deleting the answer, and I think a more appropriate action would be editing useful information from the link into the answer.

It looks like Shog9 has performed the sort of edit I had in mind on this answer, enabling us to keep around useful content.

Comment: FWIW [salvaging edit in rev 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19591602/revisions) looks more like a complete rewrite of the answer. And it seems hard to get right without domain knowledge (I for one checked if I can do it myself when it was brought to meta, and couldn't figure it). Related: [Rewrite link-only answer completely with extensive quote reformatting, or just write my own answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311628/839601)

Comment: 0.05% of the viewers deemed the answer helpful. Impressive. Where is the line drawn?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå That's not really an accurate statistic. The vast majority of viewers come from Google and don't have accounts, so can't vote at all.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Well, a score of 20 represents the top 1-2% of all answer scores on the site, so I think this is a case where an effort should be made to either 1) leave a comment and ask the user to expand the answer, or 2) edit the answer into shape. I'm not sure exactly where the line should be drawn, but 20+accept seems like it's been quite useful.

Comment: @gnat Good point -- leaving a comment is a good option when it's unclear how to edit due to the domain knowledge required. I should have left a comment in this case, especially since the answer's poster appears active on the site.

Comment: @josilber I've no problem with keeping answers which deemed helpful. All I want is clear guidelines for when to flag/ when not to flag LOAs as NAA. Nowadays I feel like the outcome of flagging is like coin flipping.

Comment: Recent Tavern conversation on this topic: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4259112#4259112

Comment: So we have to fix all link only answers then? The line for these type of problems is very thin... I think it should be a bit more clear. That answer has upvotes, but technically(according to SO policies) it should be closed.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I suppose, just like the moderator handling your flag, that you need to make a judgment call about whether the site would be in a better or worse state with the answer deleted. For the vast majority of link-only answers, the choice is easy because they are are not particularly helpful (low score, broken link, etc.). For the rare cases where they have been helpful (I would argue the answer in question is one such case), other options like commenting/editing may be better.

Comment: @Shog9 The most relevant message being: [*You'll notice that some moderators will routinely decline flags on link-only answers if the answer is heavily voted and/or accepted. The implication is, "this answer has been useful - edit it so that it continues to be useful"*](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4259138#4259138)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, the Google users *can* vote and do (occasionally). Moreover, this "anonymous feedback" is tracked and [it's not too favorable for that answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=19591602).  Currently, it has 3 "helpful" to 2 "unhelpful" responses -- which is subpar for an answer with a 20 score.

Comment: You're getting hung up on the score, @pnuts - but [the score is a heuristic here, not a reason for doing anything in and of itself.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311753/link-only-answer-not-an-answer-declined/311969#311969)

Comment: There were three flags, all of them mischaracterized the problem and none of them did a lick of good, @pnuts. I fixed the question because someone asked about it here on meta - so, helpful meta post. But again, *anyone else* could've fixed the problem as I did, with a whole lot less overhead - my hope is that this can be a learning experience for someone. As for inconsistency... With 20 million answers and counting, there are gonna be a healthy number of edge cases. Foolish hobgoblins to torment consistent minds.