# How should I flag questions that aren't questions?

Tags: discussion, flags

I have recently come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65706740/14336931) (10k rep only) which seems to be a competition-type question to solve a puzzle. Whether or not this challenge was originally created by the OP or is an assignment of some kind is, in my view, irrelevant.

My assumption is that posts of this type are off-topic for Stack Overflow and I went to flag it. Looking through the flags, though, I couldn't find one which fit with "not a question" except for the generic "severe formatting or content problems."

Does this post fall under the **Very Low Quality** flag, or is there a more appropriate response (perhaps even that it shouldn't be flagged)? I hesitate to use **Very Low Quality** because of [previous discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340866/14336931) surrounding the (mis)use of this flag.

Comment: Is it unclear to you what they're asking? It is to me. That'd be a good flag to use. Note that these flag options are now hidden under the "needs improvement" subcategory.

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't see the duplicate post in my googles. My question still could act as a signpost for others, though.

Comment: Yeah, no worries about not finding it. Technically, you could argue this isn't even a duplicate, since you're asking a support question and that other one is proposing a new feature. But the answer is the same.