# Turn the VLQ flag for answers into two new, more intuitive flags to improve flagging experience

Tags: feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts

**TL;DR**

Remove the VLQ flag and instead add flags for link-only and non-English answers that have the same effect as NAA flags but provide better guidance for flaggers.

---

The Very low-quality flag for answers has been a source of confusion for years and lead to feature requests in the past, like

- [Merge the "Not An Answer" and "Very Low Quality" flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/11682469)
- [Is there any reason to keep the "very low quality" flag? If not, can we remove it immediately? If so, can we rename it to something correct?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340866/11682469)

I have a new and somewhat more concrete idea about what to do with the VLQ flag. Flagging will be easier for flaggers and behind the scenes, while nothing changes for moderators or reviewers.

The VLQ flag has some strange and unique properties:

- [cannot flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts): older than 7 days, with positive score, in review
- any [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606) marks it helpful (even removing posts from the LQA queue)
- [auto-downvote](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=54784355#54784355) under some circumstances.

Apart from that, it's not clear how its use cases differ from those of the [NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11682469) and if you read [other discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606), it looks like an "R/A light" flag. The guidance in the flag dialog is not a great help either:

- NAA: "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."
- VLQ: "This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed."

Is there a theoretical answer you could say is NAA but not VLQ (or the other way round), especially following the above guidance? Do "I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?" or "Your answer helped me. Thank you" not also have severe content problems and are unlikely to be salvageable through editing?

From my experience, the typical NAA/VLQ answers are of the following kinds:

1. Classical NAA: "I have the same problem...", "I have a similar problem/follow-up question...", "Thank you so much for the answer..." etc. which are clearly not attempts at answering a question.
2. Link-only answer: "Have a look at this [article](...)" with all of the answer hidden behind the link and becoming useless once the link breaks.
3. Non-English answer.

Link-only and non-English answers are singled out as they are a bit of edge cases. A "true" link-only answer may be considered an attempt at answering a question and the link may lead to an excellent answer, but it's still not considered an answer because SO wants to be the place where you find answers, not just links to them. And the non-English post may be an actual answer and perhaps even include code and the non-English text may boil down to "Try this". For sure, such posts are most likely salvageable through editing and that's where the VLQ flag's property came in handy.

That's why I suggest turning the VLQ flag for answers into two new flags that are functionally (almost) equivalent to the NAA flag. The property of an edit marking the flag helpful is something that may make sense. The rest of the flag dialog would stay the same:

- spam
- rude or abusive
- not an answer
- link only
- not in English
- in need of moderator intervention

The purpose and point of the suggestion is to improve the UI for the flagger. Since the new flags have basically the same effect as NAA flags, nothing changes for moderators or reviewers and the guidance remains the same. They do not even need to know which kind of flag was originally used and, for example, you could flag a link-only answer as NAA or link-only answer (or even "not in English") because it leads to the same result. But the flags now

- reflect the posts that should be flagged as NAA
- are more intuitive since they describe the posts flaggers encounter often
- the description in the flag dialog can be improved and become proper guidance, e.g. in the case of link-only answers explain with few words that it's for answers that contain no answer to the question in the post itself and where the link itself is not the answer. Even the NAA description could be improved to say it's not for *wrong* answers.

---

<sub>Note that this is not about VLQ flags for questions which are also problematic but for different reasons. One of them is that flags for closure are hidden behind a "needs improvement" option, but that's for a different MSO discussion.</sub>

---

<sub>Also interesting how the [Privileges: flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) page notes that "very low quality" means "no amount of editing can salvage the post" yet an edit marks the flag helpful and removes the answer from the LQA queue.</sub>

Comment: I think I have *never* seen a non-English *answer*. Questions yes, but answers must be extremely rare. Is a separate flag for those useful enough to justify the noise of another flag?

Comment: I've seen plenty of them.

Comment: VLQ on answers aren't that big of an issue from mod perspective. They are handled virtually the same way as NAA. The bigger problem are VLQ flags on questions which are almost always declined and pretty much useless.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi There's quite a few of them posted daily. I don't have exact stats, but it's enough. There's also regular mod flags on non-English content that we regularly decline

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine We decline those? That's news to me

Comment: @Dharman yeah. "use standard flags", then either delete or close depending on the post type (or both if it's a question, dealer's choice). We want NAA flags or close votes, not mod flags

Comment: @Dharman The main goal is to make it easier for flaggers while for mods not much would change, except maybe for better flags. The flag dialog then covers the usual cases for NAAs with a sensible description which better guides flaggers. It tells you what to flag and also indirectly what not to (wrong or outdated answers, bad English etc. There's even more about VLQ flags on MSE). It also handles the auto-downvote and other strange VLQ flag side effects and removes the ambiguity. Btw., I completely agree with you about the VLQ flag for questions but that's even more complicated.

Comment: Considering that the VLQ flag is one of the standard flags, I'd assume this will be applied to *every* SE site... including foreign language sites and localized sites?

Comment: @AndrewT. My suggestion is just for SO, I don't know how the implementation would have to be handled. Flagging rules might be somewhat different on other SE sites.

Comment: Tangentially, regarding the post-note "*no amount of editing can salvage the post*", it's because *the system itself also* automatically flags posts as VLQ based on certain criteria, and it cannot determine whether it's actually a valid flag or not :(

Comment: Lastly, related on MSE: [Remove VLQ as a flag option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278794/241919)

Comment: I saw that one, too. There's quite a lot on MSE. But this one has an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278797) by Shog9, though it still doesn't make it entirely clear and removes the ambiguity. "Stuff that wasn't even *wrong* so much as just... Annoying." Still not clear what to use it for and too subjective (what is annoying to some may not be to others who gladly edit it). Still, what is the VLQ flag for that an NAA or R/A (gibberish) flag or even downvote + delete vote doesn't accomplish?

Comment: @AndrewT. If wording can be tweaked between sites (which I believe it can), the text can be changed to reflect the main language on the site, or languages in the case of language sites

Comment: I'm dreaming, I'm seeing a world without the VLQ flag and actual clarity.