# Review Low Quality Posts: a "wait a while" option?

Tags: discussion

Just topped the 2000 rep mark and am confronted in the Low Quality Posts queue with a "link only" Answer type of decision. But it was posted only a short time before by a new user  - rep of 1. A comment has been left that the person should expand on his answer.

It seems to me it would be reasonable to grant the person time to get the message, think about it and compose an answer (not native English-speaking).

Of course, there's no option "wait a bit and see what happens". How should something like this be handled?

Comment: Ideally, you should deal with posts as they currently are. If you don't feel like taking the appropriate action, you can skip.

Comment: Ok, thanks - guess I "passed" as that's what I did. Looks like I'm one of the "too soft-hearted crowd"...

Comment: Possibly. I think a balance of cynical gits (like me) who don't think things will improve and so just recommend deletion to things that, if remain unchanged, aren't answers and people who retain faith in humanity is probably necessary. But too often I see crap content left around because someone thought to edit a typo, not seeing that it's not an answer... So I would say "skip" rather than give a premature "looks ok".

Comment: Sometimes you can [rewrite these yourself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311628/rewrite-link-only-answer-completely-with-extensive-quote-reformatting-or-just-w).

Comment: Yes... Unfortunately, I understand very little about that particular topic and cannot read Portuguese - the language in which the linked material was written (except for the code, of course).

Comment: "Questions that need additional work or that are not a good fit for this site may be put on hold by experienced community members. While questions are on hold, they cannot be answered, but can be edited to make them eligible for reopening.

Questions that are edited within five days of being put on hold are automatically added to a reopening queue for community review. Questions that are not reopened within five days will change from [on hold] to [closed]." http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Review the post as it is now.

It does not matter whether it could be replaced with acceptable content later, that possiblity always exists. And if that should happen, the post can easily be undeleted by the author, so there's no harm.
(Unfortunately, that doesn't happen often enough. And sometimes not unless it is deleted.)

If you don't feel like handling a post properly, or don't feel able to do so, or just for fun, you can always "Skip".
Skip is never the wrong decision.

Comment: "It does not matter whether it could be replaced with acceptable content later, that possiblity always exists. And if that should happen, the post can easily be undeleted by the author, so there's no harm." THIS I was not aware of and it helps :-)

Comment: BTW: That only holds if "deleted from review", and the author undeleting then results in a notice to the mods. If "Deleted by 10K/20K delete-votes", it needs 2 others who concurr. If by mod, it needs a mod.

Comment: Oh my aching head...